# Two-port network Current Characterization

Tags: resistors, generator

I was trying to solve this two-pole exercise in which I had to found the z-parameters but I haven't find any clue in the textbook. How should I solve it?[image]

Comment: I think the english term for what you are looking for is two-port network. Here is one reference from Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-port_network .

Comment: Right. The solution is                                   0 4                                                    0 14

Comment: There was a comment, now deleted, asking if it was asked to find the z-parameters and yes, the exercise asks to find them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters \$Z_{11}\$ and \$Z_{21}\$ are obtained by applying a current \$I_1\$ to the left-hand side port (port 1), leaving port 2 (on the right-hand side) open (i.e. \$I_2=0\$), and calculating the resulting voltages \$U_1\$ and \$U_2\$ at ports 1 and 2, respectively. In this case, since there is no current flowing through \$R_b\$ (because \$I_2=0\$), the current through \$R_a\$ is the same as the current through \$R_c\$. Equating the voltage \$U_1=ri_c\$ with the voltage across \$R_a\$ and \$R_c\$ gives

$$ri_c=(R_a+R_c)i_c\tag{1}$$

Since \$r\neq R_a+R_c\$, the only solution of Eq. (1) is \$i_c=0\$. This means that \$U_1=ri_c=0\$, and \$U_2=R_ci_c=0\$, and, consequently, \$Z_{11}=Z_{21}=0\$.

In order to calculate \$Z_{12}\$ and \$Z_{22}\$ we need to apply a current \$I_2\$ to port 2 and leave port 1 open. We get

$$R_ci_c=R_a(I_2-i_c)+ri_c\tag{2}$$

Solving (2) for \$i_c\$ gives

$$i_c=\frac{R_aI_2}{R_a+R_c-r}\tag{3}$$

From (3) we can calculate \$U_1\$ and \$U_2\$:

$$U_1=ri_c=\frac{rR_aI_2}{R_a+R_c-r}\tag{4}$$

which results in

$$Z_{12}=\frac{rR_a}{R_a+R_c-r}=\frac{6\cdot 12}{18}\,\Omega=4\,\Omega\tag{5}$$

And

$$U_2=R_bI_2+R_ci_c=R_bI_2+\frac{R_aR_cI_2}{R_a+R_c-r}\tag{6}$$

from which we get

$$Z_{22}=R_b+\frac{R_aR_c}{R_a+R_c-r}=6\,\Omega+\frac{12\cdot 12}{18}\,\Omega=14\,\Omega\tag{7}$$